# KafkaSpout working example

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I recently got familiar with Apache Kafka and have a working example of a producer-consumer.

My next step is to integrate Kafka with Spout and Bolt and i am having a hard time getting the examples available(they are mostly old) working locally.

I got the following example working storm-book/examples-ch02-getting_started which is reading data from a local  text file.

The same repo has an example for storm-book/examples-ch04-spouts [kafka-spout](https://github.com/storm-book/examples-ch04-spouts)  but i am not able to get it to work.

I tried the following example as well [cep.kafka](https://github.com/buildlackey/cep/tree/master/storm%2Bkafka) but got the following error-

```
5034 [Thread-11-words] INFO  org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
5047 [Thread-11-words] ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/zookeeper/Watcher;Z)V
        at org.apache.curator.utils.DefaultZookeeperFactory.newZooKeeper(DefaultZookeeperFactory.java:29) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$2.newZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:169) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.HandleHolder$1.getZooKeeper(HandleHolder.java:94) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.HandleHolder.getZooKeeper(HandleHolder.java:55) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.reset(ConnectionState.java:219) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.start(ConnectionState.java:103) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.start(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:188) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.start(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:234) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at storm.kafka.ZkState.<init>(ZkState.java:62) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:85) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3371$fn__3386.invoke(executor.clj:522) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__460.invoke(util.clj:461) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
5049 [Thread-11-words] ERROR backtype.storm.daemon.executor -
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/zookeeper/Watcher;Z)V
        at org.apache.curator.utils.DefaultZookeeperFactory.newZooKeeper(DefaultZookeeperFactory.java:29) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$2.newZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:169) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.HandleHolder$1.getZooKeeper(HandleHolder.java:94) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.HandleHolder.getZooKeeper(HandleHolder.java:55) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.reset(ConnectionState.java:219) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.start(ConnectionState.java:103) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.start(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:188) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.start(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:234) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at storm.kafka.ZkState.<init>(ZkState.java:62) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:85) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3371$fn__3386.invoke(executor.clj:522) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__460.invoke(util.clj:461) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
5088 [Thread-11-words] ERROR backtype.storm.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
        at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:325) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4693$fn__4694.invoke(worker.clj:491) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__3272$fn__3273.invoke(executor.clj:240) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__460.invoke(util.clj:473) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I was having the same issue learning how to run create and run a Kafka Spout, I found this [Github repo](https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-kafka-0.8-plus-test) very useful, and I was able to have my KafkaSpout emitting tuples to the rest of the bolts.

This is a high level sample on how I create my topology for this.

```
public class TestTopology {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String zkIp = "192.168.59.103";

        String nimbusHost = "192.168.59.103";

        String zookeeperHost = zkIp +":2181";

        ZkHosts zkHosts = new ZkHosts(zookeeperHost);

        SpoutConfig kafkaConfig = new SpoutConfig(zkHosts, "myKafkaTopic", "", "storm");

        kafkaConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new JsonScheme() {
            @Override
            public Fields getOutputFields() {
                return new Fields("events");
            }
        });

        KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(kafkaConfig);

        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

        builder.setSpout("eventsEmitter", kafkaSpout, 8);

        builder.setBolt("eventsProcessor", new RollingCountBolt(2, 1), 8)
                .fieldsGrouping("requestsEmitter", new Fields("request"));

        //More bolts stuffzz

        Config config = new Config();

        config.setMaxTaskParallelism(5);
        config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, 2);
        config.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, nimbusHost);
        config.put(Config.NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT, 6627);
        config.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_PORT, 2181);
        config.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS, Arrays.asList(zkIp));

        try {
            StormSubmitter.submitTopology("my-topology", config, builder.createTopology());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't initialize the topology", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps,

Jose Luis

Comment: Hi Jose,Thank you so much for the link to the repo..i could run the examples form there successfully .

Comment: When I am using LocalCluster ,data is consumed by blots and kafka spout. but when i am using StormSubmitter Kafka's data is not consumed .

I am pushing data into kafka using Kafka console producer and using Storm vs 1.0.3